# Rewrite Rules Conflict with admin file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Sorry for my bad english Below is my htaccess complete file I donot have much knowledge about rewrite rules my all links work fine around index.php but if when I want to execute my admin.php file it does not allow me to go there but if I disabled this line (RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L,QSA]) in htaccess file, it works, I am very confused ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /induspkm

# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect static pages based on page name
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1&PageNo=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite images category pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1&ImageCategoryId=$2&PageNo=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1&ImageCategoryId=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule> 

# Set the default 500 page for Apache errors
ErrorDocument 500 /induspkm/500.php

#Set the defualt 404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /induspkm/404.php
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks you again for try to help me my director structure for my site is css,js,business,lib,include and files are index.php, admin.php 400.php, 500.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just above **#Redirect static pages based on page name** line:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: it works but contents of index.php file not shown now ?

Comment: Thank you very much Anubhava Sir, I have Sort out remaining problems ? You are a great experience person I have seen till now. Thank you again